# Induced Markov chain - verify Markov property and another property

Tags: proof-verification, markov-chains

First, here is how we defined induced Markov chains:

Suppose that $(X,E,P)$ is an irreducible Markov chain, where $X=(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}_0}$, $E$ is the state space and $P=(p_{i,j})_{i,j\in E}$ is the transition matrix. Suppose the Markov chain to be substochastic, which means $\sum_{j\in E}p_{i,j}\leqslant 1$ for all $i\in E$.

Let $F$ be an arbitrary non-empty subset of $E$. We define
$$
p_{x,y}^F=\mathbb{P}_x(t(F)<\infty, X_{t(F)}=y),
$$
where $\mathbb{P}_x(\cdot)$ means the probability of $\cdot$, starting in $x$ and where $t(F)$ is the first returning time of $F$.

If $y\notin F$, then $p_{x,y}^F=0$. If $y\in F$, then
$$
p_{x,y}^F=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\in E\setminus F}p_{x,x_1}p_{x_1,x_2}\ldots p_{x_{n-1},y}.
$$
The Markov chain $(X_{|F}=(X_i{_{|F}})_{i\in\mathbb{N}_0},F,P^F)$ is called the *induced Markov chain of $(X,E,P)$ on $F$*.

**Now the following task is given:**

> > Show that $(X_{|F}=(X_i{_{|F}})_{i\in\mathbb{N}_0},F,P^F)$ is in fact a Markov chain. Is it true that if $P$ is stochastic (that is: $\sum_{j\in E}p_{i,j}=1$ for all $i\in E$) then $P^F$ is stochastic?

---

(1.) I think to show that the induced Markov chain is in fact a Markov chain means to show that it fullfills the Markov property. But I do not know how I can do that.

(2.) It is
$$
\sum_{y\in F}p_{x,y}^F=\mathbb{P}_x(t(F)<\infty).
$$

I think any transient irreducible Markov chain is is an example for

$$
\sum_{y\in F}p_{x,y}^F=\mathbb{P}_x(t(F)<\infty)<1,
$$
isn't it?

In this case $P^F$ is not stochastic, no matter if $P$ is.

So the statement that from $P$ stochastic it follows that $P^F$ is stochastic should be false in general.

Am I right resp. is that justification ok?

---

It would be really great to get some feedback from you.

Thank you

Comment: You lost me at $\sum_{j \in E} p_{ij} \leq 1$ for all $i$. Why doesn't equality hold? I assume the state space $E$ is a finite or countably infinite set (else your sum makes no sense).  If the sum is strictly less than 1, there is a probability the Markov chain disappears! Anyway, an actual Markov chain is in exactly one state of the state space every time step, and so your sum must equal 1 since we must go somewhere next.

Comment: Do not understand exactly your point. This is the definition of substochastic: There is at least one row in the transition matrix which entries do not sum up to 1 but are smaller than 1.

Comment: That is the definition of a _substochastic matrix_.  But a Markov chain has a transition probability matrix where all rows must sum to 1. Substochastic matrices are irrelevant unless you are only considering a portion of the state space.

Comment: Formally, for all states $i \in E$ we have $1 = Pr[X(t+1) \in E|X(t)=i] = \sum_{j \in E} Pr[X(t+1)=j|X(t)=i]= \sum_{j\in E} P_{ij}$.

Comment: I see your point. Nevertheless the professor wrote on the blackboard that the transition matrix is supposed to be stochastic.

Comment: I don't think this problem should have a bounty.  You already have the answer to the second question, and the first seems (after suspending disbelief on the basic definition of state space) to just require an argument that says, given you returned to $F$, where you go next is independent of history.

Comment: What exactly is not okay or complete with my try to verify the Markov property for the induced Markov Chain?

Comment: I would just say that anything in the future is independent of the past, given the current state.  You can formally prove that from the Markov definition but I don't know if you need to go into that level of formality.  But, for example, you can prove Pr[X(t+2)=j|X(t)=i, history before t] is independent of history before t. Or that Pr[X(t+n)=j|X(t+n-1) !=j, ..., X(t+1)!=j | X(t)=i, history before t] is independent of history (the latter is the probability that the first time to return to $j$ is  $n$  steps later).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I missunderstand you. But what is your reason that the future is independent of the past, given the current state?

Comment: @Michael I need a formal proof. But do not know how to make it.

Comment: Well, for example, you can prove $Pr[X(t+2)=j|X(t)=i, History(t)]$ is independent of history by conditioning on all possible values of $X(t+1)$ and using the Markov property. In general, you just use conditioning with the Markov property.

Comment: @Michael Cannot manage that. Do not know how to prove that for the induced markov chain. Maybe you can show me?

Comment: In that case, perhaps the problem you have is too ambitious.  You should focus on understanding the statement "the future is conditionally independent of the past given the current state."  For example, try to prove that $Pr[X(t+2)=j|X(t)=i, X(t-1)=i_{t-1}, ..., X(0)=i_0] = Pr[X(t+2)=j|X(t)=i]$ by using the law of total probability and conditioning on all possible values of $X(t+1)$. Note that $Pr[C|D] = \sum_{k \in S} Pr[C|D, Y=k]Pr[Y=k|D]$ for any events $C,D$ and random variable $Y$ that takes values in a discrete set $S$.  You just have to do it. Any more "hint" would be a full solution.